# Material UI fade scroll styling on ImageList

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui, imagelist, scroll-position

I have a horizontally scrolling ImageList using Material UI V5, and I would like to fade the edges so that the cutoff isn't as harsh. I have figured out how to fade the edges, but I would only like the edges to fade until the user has scrolled to the start or end of the list (so when the user is at the start of the list the right is faded, and at the end the left is faded, and on larger screens with no scroll there is no fade). What is the easiest way for me to achieve this within MUI ImageList? I can style the object conditionally but can't seem to get scroll position.

[image]

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import ImageList from '@mui/material/ImageList';
import ImageListItem from '@mui/material/ImageListItem';
import ImageListItemBar from '@mui/material/ImageListItemBar';
import { styled } from "@mui/system"
import { NoEncryption } from '@mui/icons-material';


export default function TitlebarBelowImageList() {

  return (
    <AdBarContainer>
    <ImageList sx={{ 
      width: "100%",
      gridAutoFlow: "column",
      gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fill,minmax(15em, 1fr)) !important",
      gridAutoColumns: "minmax(15em, 1fr)",
      overflowX:'scroll',
      maskImage: 'linear-gradient(to left, black calc(100% - 48px), transparent 100%)',
      maskImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, black 48px, black calc(100% - 48px), transparent 100%)',
      }}
      gap= {10}
      variant= 'standard'
      rowHeight= "auto"
      >
      {itemData.map((item) => (
        <ImageListItem key={item.key}>
          <img
            src={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format`}
            srcSet={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format&dpr=2 2x`}
            alt={item.title}
            loading="lazy"
            style={{borderRadius: 10}}
          />
          <ImageListItemBar
            title={item.title}
            subtitle={<span>{item.subtitle}</span>}
            position="below"
          />
        </ImageListItem>
      ))}
    </ImageList>
    </AdBarContainer>
  );
}

const itemData = [
  {
    key: 1,
    img: '/img.jpg',
    title: 'title',
    subtitle: 'subtitle',
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    img: '/img.jpg',
    title: 'title',
    subtitle: 'subtitle',
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    img: '/img.jpg',
    title: 'title',
    subtitle: 'subtitle',
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    img: '/img.jpg',
    title: 'title',
    subtitle: 'subtitle',
  },
  {
    key: 5,
    img: '/img.jpg',
    title: 'title',
    subtitle: 'subtitle',
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-sun-d8is30?file=/demo.tsx) which I think is what you are looking for.

Here is you code updated with the answer:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import ImageList from "@mui/material/ImageList";
import ImageListItem from "@mui/material/ImageListItem";
import ImageListItemBar from "@mui/material/ImageListItemBar";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import { NoEncryption } from "@mui/icons-material";

const itemData = [
  {
    key: 1,
    img: "/img.jpg",
    title: "title",
    subtitle: "subtitle"
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    img: "/img.jpg",
    title: "title",
    subtitle: "subtitle"
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    img: "/img.jpg",
    title: "title",
    subtitle: "subtitle"
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    img: "/img.jpg",
    title: "title",
    subtitle: "subtitle"
  },
  {
    key: 5,
    img: "/img.jpg",
    title: "title",
    subtitle: "subtitle"
  }
];

export default function TitlebarBelowImageList() {
  const [horizontalScroll, setHorizontalScroll] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const imageListEl = document.querySelector("#imageList");

    imageListEl?.addEventListener(
      "scroll",
      () => {
        console.log("position left is", imageListEl.scrollLeft);
        setHorizontalScroll(imageListEl?.scrollLeft);
      },
      { passive: true }
    );
  }, [horizontalScroll]);

  return (
    <AdBarContainer>
    <ImageList
      id="imageList"
      sx={{
        width: "100%",
        gridAutoFlow: "column",
        gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fill,minmax(15em, 1fr)) !important",
        gridAutoColumns: "minmax(15em, 1fr)",
        overflowX: "scroll",
        maskImage:
          horizontalScroll > 0
            ? [
                "linear-gradient(to left, black calc(100% - 48px), transparent 100%)",
                "linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, black 48px, black calc(100% - 48px), transparent 100%)"
              ]
            : [""]
      }}
      gap={10}
      variant="standard"
      rowHeight="auto"
    >
      {console.log("pos", horizontalScroll)}
      {itemData.map((item) => (
        <ImageListItem key={item.key}>
          <img
            src={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format`}
            srcSet={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format&dpr=2 2x`}
            alt={item.title}
            loading="lazy"
            style={{ borderRadius: 10 }}
          />
          <ImageListItemBar
            title={item.title}
            subtitle={<span>{item.subtitle}</span>}
            position="below"
          />
        </ImageListItem>
      ))}
    </ImageList>
    </AdBarContainer>
  );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is working somewhat! Only problem is both fades activate when I scroll. Is there a way to only activate them until you reach the start or end of the imagelist? For instance when the page first loads, only the right side is faded. And when you scroll to the end only the left side is faded.

Comment: @c011N I am controlling when to show and hide based on a condition inside the `maskImage` property (using `horizontalScroll > 0`). You can change it accordingly.

Comment: I see, can this work with 2 conditions (end of scroll as well)?

Comment: Of course, you just need to add it to the condition once you identify the end of the scroll

Comment: I got start of scroll and end of scroll working, but how would you write a conditional for when there is no scroll? I'm trying something like       scrollWidth == null ? ["none"]   but not getting any results

Comment: Start of scroll is `0`, end of scroll is the width of your slider component. I created the const `horizontalScroll` which initially is set to `0`. So in your case you can say that when `horizontalScroll ` is between 10 and 500 (example numbers) don't show the shadow (`maskImage `). I am not sure what exactly you mean that you need to check if is null (it will always have a value as as i mentioned I set it to `0`). Please provide the codesandbox with your added code.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, here is the codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-shadow-f78iuh?file=/demo.tsx
I declared scrollWidth and clientWidth as well as horizontalScroll

Comment: You are close to solving it. You need to wrap all the ternary operators inside another `if` statement that you compare the widths so you can identify if there is a scrollBar.  If there isn't then you return `[""]`. If you initial question has been answered please consider marking it to help future users with similar question. Thanks